# In d3.js treemap layout how to make the last child clickable and fill the entire treemap layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

Im using d3.js treemap layout . In the treemap , on clicking the parent segment with the children property it transitions into its respective child sub segments . But on clicking the last child without any children property it wont make the transition happens to fill only that child node in the entire layout . In the code that im working on I can redirect to a new window on click of the last child but not sure how to make the transition happening .

Find my code in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-thunder-l024x

```
class TreemapChart extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 },
      width = 960,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      transitioning;

    var x = d3.scale
      .linear()
      .domain([0, width])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale
      .linear()
      .domain([0, height])
      .range([0, height]);

    var treemap = d3.layout
      .treemap()
      .children(function(d, depth) {
        return depth ? null : d._children;
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
      })
      .ratio((height / width) * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
      .round(false);

    var svg = d3
      .select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
      .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
      .style("margin.right", -margin.right + "px")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
    //   .on("mousemove", function (d) {
    //     tool.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px")
    //     tool.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 20 + "px")
    //     tool.style("display", "inline-block");
    //     tool.html(d.children ? null : d.name + "<br>" );
    // }).on("mouseout", function (d) {
    //     tool.style("display", "none");
    // });

    var grandparent = svg.append("g").attr("class", "grandparent");

    grandparent
      .append("rect")
      .attr("y", -margin.top)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", margin.top);

    grandparent
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 6)
      .attr("y", 6 - margin.top)
      .attr("dy", ".35em");

    function dataMap(root) {
      initialize(root);
      accumulate(root);
      accumulateCount(root);
      layout(root);
      display(root);

      function initialize(root) {
        root.x = root.y = 0;
        root.dx = width;
        root.dy = height;
        root.depth = 0;
      }

      // Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
      // treemap layout, but not here because of our custom implementation.
      // We also take a snapshot of the original children (_children) to avoid
      // the children being overwritten when when layout is computed.
      function accumulate(d) {
        return (d._children = d.children)
          ? (d.value = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) {
              return p + accumulate(v);
            }, 0))
          : d.value;
      }

      function accumulateCount(d) {
        return (d._children = d.children)
          ? (d.count = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) {
              return p + accumulateCount(v);
            }, 0))
          : d.count;
      }

      function layout(d) {
        if (d._children) {
          treemap.nodes({ _children: d._children });
          d._children.forEach(function(c) {
            c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
            c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
            c.dx *= d.dx;
            c.dy *= d.dy;
            c.parent = d;
            layout(c);
          });
        }
      }

      function display(d) {
        // console.log(d);
        grandparent
          .datum(d.parent)
          .on("click", transition)
          .select("text")
          .text(name(d));

        var g1 = svg
          .insert("g", ".grandparent")
          .datum(d)
          .attr("class", "depth");

        var g = g1
          .selectAll("g")
          .data(d._children)
          .enter()
          .append("g");

        g.filter(function(d) {
          return d._children;
        })
          .classed("children", true)
          .on("click", transition);

        g.selectAll(".child")
          .data(function(d) {
            return d._children || [d];
          })
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "child")
          .call(rect);

        g.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "parent")
          .call(rect)
          .on("click", function(d) {
            if (!d._children) {
              window.open(d.url);
            }
          })
          .append("title")
          .text(function(d) {
            return `${d.name} (${d.count})`;
          });

        g.append("text")
          .attr("dx", "1rem")
          .attr("dy", "2rem")
          .text(function(d) {
            return `${d.name}`;
          })
          .call(text);

        function transition(d) {
          self.props.onClickSegment(d.metricsValue);
          if (transitioning || !d) return;
          transitioning = true;

          var g2 = display(d),
            t1 = g1.transition().duration(750),
            t2 = g2.transition().duration(750);

          // Update the domain only after entering new elements.
          x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
          y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

          // Enable anti-aliasing during the transition.
          svg.style("shape-rendering", null);

          // Draw child nodes on top of parent nodes.
          svg.selectAll(".depth").sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.depth - b.depth;
          });

          // Fade-in entering text.
          g2.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

          // Transition to the new view.
          t1.selectAll("text")
            .call(text)
            .style("fill-opacity", 0);
          t2.selectAll("text")
            .call(text)
            .style("fill-opacity", 1);
          t1.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
          t2.selectAll("rect").call(rect);

          // Remove the old node when the transition is finished.
          t1.remove().each("end", function() {
            svg.style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
            transitioning = false;
          });
        }

        return g;
      }

      function text(text) {
        text
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x) + 6;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y) + 6;
          });
      }

      function rect(rect) {
        rect
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y);
          })
          .attr("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x);
          })
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y);
          });
      }

      function name(d) {
        return d.parent ? name(d.parent) + " / " + d.name : d.name;
      }
    }
    dataMap(dataObj);
  }
  handleClick = d => {
    // this.props.onClickSegment(d.metricsValue);
    console.log("The text", d.metricsValue);
  };
  render() {
    return <p id="chart" />;
  }
}
```

I need to click the last child and on clicking the last child should fill the layout with the respective breadcrumb like in the code.